# How to automate Bing search queries in all existing profile on MS Edge using code given

Tags: powershell, microsoft-edge, browser-automation

I was trying to automate Bing search with the following code using PowerShell :

```
for ($a = 0; $a -lt 45; $a++) {
    $RandomWord = Get-Random -InputObject (get-content  C:\Users\ashq4\OneDrive\Documents\RandomwordList.txt)
    $RandomQuestion = Get-Random -InputObject("what+is+","Definition+","Thesaurus+for+","Examples+of+","prefixes+for+","suffixes+for+")
    Start-Process microsoft-edge:http://www.bing.com/search?q=$RandomQuestion$RandomWord -windowStyle Minimized
    start-sleep -Milliseconds 1500
}
start-sleep -Milliseconds 2000
Start-Process microsoft-edge:https://www.bing.com/rewards/dashboard
write-Host Done
Break Script
```

This code opens 45 tabs in my default ms edge profile. it uses random search words from a text file.

It works well. **My question is how I can open all of my profiles that exist in the Edge browser to perform this automation in separate windows. For example, If I have two profiles. I want the search to happen in each profile with separate two windows carrying out the search automation in 45 tabs each. i.e., 45 tabs in 2 windows respectively.**

I asked AI and it provided this:

```
function Execute-ProfileScript($profileArgument) {
    # Execute the Bing.ps1 script 45 times
    for ($j = 0; $j -lt 45; $j++) {
        $RandomWord = Get-Random -InputObject (get-content  C:\Users\ashq4\OneDrive\Documents\RandomwordList.txt)
        $RandomQuestion = Get-Random -InputObject("what+is+","Definition+","Thesaurus+for+","Examples+of+","prefixes+for+","suffixes+for+")
        Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" -ArgumentList "--profile-directory=$profileArgument http://www.bing.com/search?q=$RandomQuestion$RandomWord" -WindowStyle Minimized
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1500
    }

    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" -ArgumentList "--profile-directory=$profileArgument https://www.bing.com/rewards/dashboard"
    Write-Host "Done with $profileArgument"
}

# Get the list of existing profiles
$edgeUserDataPath = "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Edge\User Data"
$profiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $edgeUserDataPath -Filter "Profile*" | ForEach-Object { $_.Name }

# Filter out the "Default" profile
$profiles = $profiles | Where-Object { $_ -ne "Default" }

foreach ($profileName in $profiles) {
    # Open Edge with the specified profile
    $profileArgument = "--profile-directory=$profileName"
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" -ArgumentList "$profileArgument --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end --site-per-process"

    # Execute the script for the opened profile
    Execute-ProfileScript -profileArgument $profileArgument
}
```

It creates new profile its own. Not working as expected but somehow it is opening profiles but creating new ones.

Answer (score 1):

I found the profile directory:
--profile-directory=`"Profile $pro`"

So It'd be like this:

```
Start-Process "msedge" -ArgumentList "--profile-directory=`"Profile $pro`" https://www.bing.com/search?q=Bing+$_"
```

And I'd recommend to randomize the start-sleep part, between 1 and 3 seconds as this:

```
$rnd = get-random -minimum 1000 -maximum 3000
start-sleep -Milliseconds $rnd
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the existing profile, just set the `$profileName` value in the code. You can find the profile name in *edge://version/* under **Profile path**. For example, the profile name is **Default** in below picture:

[image]

If you set `$profileName = "Default"`, Edge will open with that existing profile.